# Please help identifying this brush-written typeface

Tags: typography, font-identification

[image: This is a painted sign that I am trying to identify the font]

This is a painted sign I found and I really like the font. I cannot identify this font. I have tried several of the sites where I can upload a picture but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where does the image comes from?

Comment: This looks like hand-lettering based on an existing typeface. Shoddy lettering, if you'd ask me, judging by the rising baseline under the 'g'.

Comment: I am quite 'green' when it comes to fonts/typeface.  If this seems shoddy, would you suggest something that has a similar feel?  I won't be handlettering

Comment: then you do not have to worry, the typeface is fine. it is the rising baseline that makes the lettering shoddy.

Answer (score 2):

The font IMHO looks very similar to [Script TM](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/script-mt/)

[image]